# C++ Quaternion Equation Program

Tags: c++, math, quaternions

I'm trying to write a program that **multiplies 2 quaternion** equations. Here's are my 2 initial quaternions:

q1=2−i+j+3k, and

q2=−1+i+4j−2k

I allow the user to type their own numbers representing each top component from `a1` to `a4`, and bottom components from `b1` to `b4`, like this:

```
cout << "Enter the [A1] value: ";
cin >> a1;
cout << "Enter the [A2] value: ";
cin >> a2;
cout << "Enter the [A3] value: ";
cin >> a3;
cout << "Enter the [A4] value: ";
cin >> a4;
cout << "Enter the [B1] value: ";
cin >> b1;
cout << "Enter the [B2] value: ";
cin >> b2;
cout << "Enter the [B3] value: ";
cin >> b3;
cout << "Enter the [B4] value: ";
cin >> b4;
```

I then multiply `a1` by every "`b`" element, `a2` by every "`b`" element and so on, then I store these new values in variables, I've followed the table and labelled each new variable so I know if it represents either `ij` or `k`:

```
multiplec1 = b1 * a1;   // num
multiplec2 = b2 * a1;   // i
multiplec3 = b3 * a1;   // j
multiplec4 = b4 * a1;   // k

multiplec5 = b1 * a2;   // -i
multiplec5 = -multiplec5;
multiplec6 = b2 * a2;   // num
multiplec7 = b3 * a2;   // k
multiplec8 = b4 * a2;   // -j
multiplec6 = -multiplec6;

multiplec9 = b1 * a3;   // j
multiplec10 = b2 * a3;  // -k
multiplec10 = -multiplec10;
multiplec11 = b3 * a3;  // num
multiplec12 = b4 * a3;  // i

multiplec13 = b1 * a4;  // num
multiplec14 = b2 * a4;  // i
multiplec15 = b3 * a4;  // j
multiplec16 = b4 * a4;  // k
```

Lastly, I add up all the appropriate `ijk` values:

```
finalint = multiplec1 + multiplec6 + multiplec11 + multiplec15;
finalI = multiplec2 + multiplec5 + multiplec12 + multiplec14;
finalJ = multiplec3 + multiplec8 + multiplec9 + multiplec15;
finalK = multiplec4 + multiplec7 + multiplec10 + multiplec16;
```

for some reason, when I display my "`final`" variables, the numbers seem to be completely different than the ones I done on paper so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm not sure what.

Would someone care to help me figure out where in my calculations I've gone wrong here and why I'm getting the wrong values?

**[EDIT]**

Here's the values I should be getting:

9 -11i - 7j - 12k

But for some reason I'm getting this instead:

15 2i 21j -15k

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check your work as you go?

Comment: Please post the numbers you expect and the numbers you get.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yeah I have and the multiplication values seem to be fine before and after, it seems to be when I'm updating the "final" variables I believe

Comment: I've just updated my question showing for you @MaxVollmer

Comment: Since you know how to use a debugger this should be easy then. Add a few temporary variables for each stage of the final calculations, then walk through with the debugger to examine them. Compare those results to what you calculated by hand, and you can pinpoint exactly where you and the program differ.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most surpising part here is that both your paper calculations and your program are wrong at the same time but in different ways. Actually
[`2−i+j+3k` multiplied by `−1+i+4j−2k` is `1 - 11 i + 8 j - 12 k`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quaternion+2%E2%88%92i%2Bj%2B3k+multiplied+by+%E2%88%921%2Bi%2B4j%E2%88%922k) and the logic is

```
  1   = -2 +1 -4 +6 = 2*(-1) + (-i)*i + j*4j + 3k*(-2k)
-11*i = (+2 +1 -2 -12)*i = 2*i + (-i)*(-1) + j*(-2k) + 3k*4j
  8*j = (+8 -1 -2 +3)*j = 2*4j +j*(-1) + (-i)*(-2k) +  3k*i
-12*k = (-4 -3 -4 -1)*k =  2*(-2k) + (3k)*(-1) + (-i)*4j + j*i
```

Note that for quaternions multiplication is noncommutative. For examlpe, `i*j = k` while `j*i = -k`. You can find the full [multiplication table in the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)). So check your code against that table because there are quite a few errors there.